# Fail to resize Ubuntu VDI, using virtualbox on windows7

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, virtualbox, partitioning, virtual-machine

I am trying to resize storage of my Ubuntu on Windows 7 with VirtualBox. The current storage configuration is dynamic 10 GB

- Command used:

```
.\VBoxManage modifyhd "C:\Users\Administrator\VirtualBox VMs\Ubuntu\Ubuntu.vdi" --resize 20000
```

- Command output:

```
C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox>.\VBoxManage modifyhd "C:\Users\Administrator\VirtualBox VMs\Ubuntu\Ubuntu.vdi" --resize 20000
0%...
Progress state: VBOX_E_NOT_SUPPORTED
VBoxManage.exe: error: Failed to resize medium
VBoxManage.exe: error: Resizing to new size 20971520000 is not yet supported for medium 'C:\Users\Administrator\VirtualBox VMs\Ubuntu\Ubuntu.vdi'
VBoxManage.exe: error: Details: code VBOX_E_NOT_SUPPORTED (0x80bb0009), component MediumWrap, interface IMedium
VBoxManage.exe: error: Context: "enum RTEXITCODE __cdecl handleModifyMedium(struct HandlerArg *)" at line 768 of file VBoxManageDisk.cpp
```

Please advise why is it failing to resize

Comment: Try a value with `20480` in that command.

Comment: Yes, tried it already but the result is the same